# HTMX: hx-boost and relative URLs

Tags: htmx

I have encountered an interesting problem. First, imagine following URL structure:

- /admin

  - /admin/[id] (this redirects to /admin/[id]/scores)
  - /admin/[id]/scores
  - /admin/[id]/answers

I configured all 3 pages to have `hx-boost="true"` on the body tag and use boosted anchor tags for all my navigation.

Here are the simple steps to reprodure my problem:

0. I load my page on `/admin`
1. I navigate to `admin/[id]` (notice how I use a relative path)
2. I get navigated to `/admin/[id]/scores` successfully
3. I click on a link in the tab bar to navigate "horizontally" to `answers` (The browser shows `/admin/[id]/answers` when hovering over the anchor tag)
4. I get a 404, because HTMX tries to load `/answers` instead of `/admin/[id]/answers`

Also the other way around:

0. I load my page on `/admin/[id]/answers`
1. I navigate to `/admin` (this time with an absolute path)
2. I get navigated to `/admin` successfully
3. I click on a link to `admin/[id]` (now a relative path again)
4. I get a 404, because HTMX tries to load `/admin/q/[id]/admin/q/[id]` (huh?)

Did I miss something in the documentation regarding hx-boost and relative URLs? Because if I remove the `hx-boost="true"` from my links that navigate "vertically" instead of "horizontally" everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

this looks like https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/1476

> Order of hx-boost checking and history pushing causes issues with relative links

at the time of posting the workaround seems to be to disable link boosting.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I missed that issue. Hope it will be fixed at some point.

Comment: @maiksch fwiw, I found this question before I found the issue when I encountered the problem in my own service.